# Ubuntu 16.04 very slow to boot on my computer.

Tags: system-installation

I have dvds for Linux Lite 32 and 64 bit, would 32 be faster? 
(x86_64) I have 2.8 ram

Answer (score 0):

this is from my opinion based on my personal research. It is not an issues if you intend to use either 32 or 64 bit as long as your processor support it(32 or 64). If your processor capacity is 64 bit, you are recommended to use 64 bit OS for best performance. Kindly edit this answer if have any better suggestions.
Thanks.